# How to create uri correctly with dbFlow Android

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2, dbflow

I need to create URI using DBFlow Content Provider. It is not generating URIs correctly.

This my Database and Content Provider class

[image]

This is my first Table Endpoint

[image]

And this is my second Table Endpoint

[image]

I need of URIs like this:

[image]

but this is how DBFlow is generating URIs:

[image]

what I am doing wrong?
I think that `@PathSegment` annotation should create `/*/#` in the URI.

Answer (score 0):

I have generated CONTENT_URI by using this method

```
public static final String ENDPOINT = "PostData";
@ContentUri(path = ENDPOINT, type = ContentUri.ContentType.VND_MULTIPLE + ENDPOINT)
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(AppDatabase.BASE_CONTENT_URI + AppDatabase.AUTHORITY
        + "/" + ENDPOINT);
```

And my database class looks like this

```
@ContentProvider(authority = AppDatabase.AUTHORITY,
        database = AppDatabase.class,
        baseContentUri = AppDatabase.BASE_CONTENT_URI)
@Database(name = AppDatabase.NAME, version = AppDatabase.VERSION)
public class AppDatabase {

    public static final String NAME = "AppDatabase"; // we will add the .db extension

    public static final int VERSION = 2;

    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.hashx19.pristinekashmir.dbflowcontentprovider";

    public static final String BASE_CONTENT_URI = "content://"; }
```

you can also check how i have used content provider in cursor loader [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39146360/5204702)